# Keras save_weights and ModelCheckpoint Difference

Tags: python, keras

I save keras model by two ways
1. "ModelCheckpoint"
2. "save_weights" after training model

But performance of those two are different when load trained model using "load_weights" and "predict"

My code is as follows

#### Train & Save Model

```
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("Model_weights.hdf5", verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
```

`early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=20, verbose=1, restore_best_weights=True)`

```
hist = Model.fit(x=train_dict, y=train_label, 
                       batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, 
                       validation_data=(valid_dict, valid_label),
                       callbacks=[csv_logger, early_stopping, model_checkpoint])

Model.save_weights("Model_weights.h5")
```

#### Load Trained Model and Test

```
Model = create_model() # Construct model skeleton 

hdf5_model = load_model("Model_weights.hdf5")

h5_model = load_model("Model_weights.h5")
```

There are difference between "hdf5_model.predict(train)" and "h5_model.predict(train)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to understand what ModelCheckpoint actually does. It saves only the best weight. You can see the loss and accuracy for each epoch during training. It changes on each epoch. Sometimes it increases and sometimes it decreases as the model continuously updating its weights.

Let's assume a situation. You're training your model for 50 epochs. It's possible that you will get loss = 0.25 on the 45th epoch and loss = 0.37 on the 50th epoch. It's very normal. ModelCheckpoint will only save 45th epochs weight. It won't update on the 50th epoch. ModelCheckpoint only saves the weight only if loss decreases(you can also change the logic via parameter). But if you save the weights after training is completed, it will save with a loss of 0.37 which is higher.

It's very normal that the model saved via ModelCheckpoint has lower loss value and final model has a higher value. That's why you're getting different predictions from these two models.

If you take a look at the graph below, you can see the best loss value was achieved on the 98th epoch. So your ModelCheckpoint saving the weights on 98th epoch and never updating it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. According to your description, except last epoch gives best performance, ModelCheckpoint would save best performance among epochs. Then, save_weights save what? Because I also used EarlyStopping with restore_best_weights=True, but Model.save_weights gives higher loss comparing with ModelCheckpoint. Why...? (I edit my question codes)

Comment: Then final save_weights after it finishes training always saves the last epochs weight. But as you said you used restore_best_weights=True, it should restore the best weights among all epochs. But you're missing a parameter, please try setting the parameter 'monitor' for ModelCheckpoint also. Also add 'mode' param to be safe. I see no point of using ModelCheckpoint if you're restoring best weights as you're only saving the best using ModelCheckpoint. You can save every best weights using ModelCheckpoint though. That's not the question though. Please try adding missing params and compare again.

Comment: Thanks. Your advice was adding parameter {monitor='val_loss', mode='auto'} as well as {save_best_only=True} to ModelCheckpoint. And use saved model through ModelCheckpoint. Because save_weights only saves last epochs so it doesn't secure best performance weight.

Comment: Yes. But if you use early stopping with restore_best = true and if you only need the model with minimum loss, you don't need to use modelcheckpoint. Sometimes it's possible that your global minima is discovered later. My suggestion is: if you still not happy with accuracy, decrease the LR, set higher number of epochs and do not use early stopping. Use CheckPoint only to save weights. Then you can compare all the checkpoints and decide which one to use.